# Gmagick fails to install from source

Tags: 12.04, php

I'm trying to install gmagick php extension from source, using these commands:

```
    mkdir gmagick
    cd gmagick
    mkdir build
    mkdir local

    cd $HOME/gmagick/build
    wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/1.3/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
    tar zxvf GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
    cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.18
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/gmagick/local --enable-shared --enable-symbol-prefix
    make
    make install
    export PATH=$HOME/gmagick/local/bin:$PATH

    cd $HOME/gmagick/build
    wget http://pecl.php.net/get/gmagick-1.1.2RC1.tgz
    tar zxvf gmagick-1.1.2RC1.tgz
    cd gmagick-1.1.2RC1
    phpize
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/gmagick/local/lib/pkgconfig
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/gmagick/local --with-gmagick=$HOME/gmagick/local
    make
    make install
    echo "extension=gmagick.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/gmagick.ini

    service php5-fpm restart
```

The lines below contain the command that tests if is installed correctly and it's output.

```
    php -i | grep gmagick
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gmagick.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gmagick.so: undefined symbol: MagickBlurImage in Unknown on line 0
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gmagick.ini,
    PWD => /root/gmagick/build/gmagick-1.1.2RC1
    OLDPWD => /root/gmagick/build
    _SERVER["PWD"] => /root/gmagick/build/gmagick-1.1.2RC1
    _SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /root/gmagick/build
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue myself. The problem is the `--enable-symbol-prefix` flag when configuring GraphicsMagick. The Gmagick extension must not be able to find the symbols because the `--enable-symbol-prefix` "enables prefixing library symbols with 'Gm'" (from the [documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html)).

Here is a script I wrote to install GraphicsMagick from source - https://gist.github.com/bhdouglass/7851749.